# The specified user does not have a valid profile. Unable to load XXX.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

In a website, I get this error:

```
The specified user does not have a valid profile.  Unable to load XXX.dll
```

This happens when any page load is attempted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set to `Load User Profile` true in the apppool advanced settings in IIS:

[image: Screenshot of apppool advanced settings]

More info is here: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Why is the user profile required to load a DLL file?